# Implementing list Interface property with in a Interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface which has the same interface as list in property.
How do I assign the value to `ListSequences` property in ClassA?
I need to do lazy initialization on `ListSequences` property as I don't want to load all the values initially.

```
public interface IInterfaceA : IBase
{
        int Sequence { get; }
        IList<IInterfaceA> ListSequences { get; }
        string ApprovedBy { get; }
        DateTime ApprovedOn { get; }
}

public interface IBase
{
        string ID { get; }
        string Name { get; }
        string Notes { get; }
}

 public class ClassA : Base, IInterfaceA
 {
        private readonly int _sequence;
        private readonly string _approvedBy;
        private readonly DateTime _approvedOn;

        public ClassA(string Id, string name, string notes, int sequence,string approvedBy, DateTime approvedOn )
            : base(Id, name, notes)
        {
            _sequence = sequence;
            _approvedBy = approvedBy;
            _approvedOn = approvedOn;
        }
        public int Sequence => _sequence;
        public string ApprovedBy => _approvedBy;
        public DateTime ApprovedOn => _approvedOn;
}
```

Comment: Is here a reason `class ClassA` isn't using auto-properties?

Comment: Please explain why `interface IInterfaceA` contains a collection of other `IInterfaceA` objects - and _how_ it's lazy-loaded - there's no IO code (databases? files? services?) in your post so far...

Comment: Something happening in the Base class we don't get to see? You need to somewhere create the ListSequences List (property only has a getter so can't be delivered from the outside)

Comment: Sorry i changed the implementation by moving the list outside of the interface. But still I am interested to know how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from initializing a list in the constructor of `ClassA`?
Also, There really is no need for specifying backing fields in such cases:

```
 public class ClassA : Base, IInterfaceA
 {
        public ClassA(string Id, string name, string notes, int sequence,string approvedBy, DateTime approvedOn )
            : base(Id, name, notes)
        {
            Sequence = sequence;
            ApprovedBy = approvedBy;
            ApprovedOn = approvedOn;
            ListSequences = new List<IInterfaceA>();
        }
        public int Sequence {get;}
        public string ApprovedBy {get;}
        public DateTime ApprovedOn {get;}
        public IList<IInterfaceA> ListSequences {get;}
}
```

Now your `ClassA` implements the `IInterfaceA` and you can add or remove items to the list whenever you want to in your code.